# implementation of equals and hashCode on recursive objects (JPA @ManyToMany)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, recursion, comparison

I have recently implemented some JPA-Entites with a bidirectional mapping like the following example.

```
public class User {
    @ManyToMany(...)
    private List<Group> groups;

    // ...
}

public class Group {
    @ManyToMany(...)
    private List<User> users;

    // ...
}
```

I have also implemented `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` on both classes, including a comparison on each of these entities for their assigned groups respectively their assigned users.

```
public class User {
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // ...

        Objects.equals(this.groups, obj.groups);

        // ...
    }
}

public class Group {
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // ...

        Objects.equals(this.users, obj.users);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Obviously this would end in a `StackOverflowError` because `equals(Object obj)` is called infinite times if a user is assigned to a group.

Is there a best practice for this kind of situations or should I just exclude these collections from `equals(Object obj)`?

Thanks for you for your help :)

Comment: Great question, +1; this is interesting! One thing I'd ask myself is if it really makes sense to compare each of these entities in terms of the other entity. For example, can two users with the same IDs/usernames (assuming you have some sort of unique key), but different lists of associated groups, coexist? If not, then why consider the list as part of `equals`? Similarly for groups, you'd expect the group to have some sort of unique ID (e.g., a name), so why go through the hassle of comparing the user-set, when you can just compare the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the best practice would be to compare two entities by comparing their unique IDs. A user does not become a different user by entering a new group. much less, by changing one of the groups she belongs to.

domain specific comparisons could be various, and should be implemented in seperate comparators.

Comment: I thought of comparing the their IDs too. I also like the idea of "outsourcing" the specific comparison.